# Emacs freezes on javascript mode if I enter a newline after a dot character

Tags: javascript, crash

Cursor is on the dot, I press newline, emacs hangs. This happens often to me I kill emacs and restart it. I come to this situation to break long lines at function calls at dot character.

```
  situation('8/8/8/8/8/8/8/R3K2R w - - 0 1')!.actors

  let [long, short] = ;
```

You need to try harder, play with `.` and newline break for example this hangs:

```
laskjdf
  .jalksdf
  .aksdfl.
  .lkajsdf
.
```

This is my config: https://github.com/eguneys/dotfiles .
Actually I am using `typescript-mode` which I installed from melpa.
I don't use neither fly-check or fly-make, syntax just highlights out of the blue.
I don't know what `C-h v major-mode` or `C-h minor-mode` does `C-h` is bound to `delete-character` to me.

Here's a `describe-mode`:

```
Enabled minor modes: Auto-Composition Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption
Blink-Cursor Column-Number Electric-Indent File-Name-Shadow Font-Lock
Global-Eldoc Global-Font-Lock Line-Number Mouse-Wheel Tool-Bar Tooltip
Transient-Mark Whole-Line-Or-Region
```

Here's a `describe-variable major-mode`:

Its value is ‘typescript-mode’

Comment: You need provide more information. What's output of `C-h v major-mode`? What's output of `C-h m`? What packages you use in javascript development? flycheck or flymake? Please provide a minimum code example to reproduce the issue? As I tested, both `js-mode` and `js2-mode` are fine.

Comment: Minimal testing of `typescript-mode` in Emacs 27.2 reproduces the issue.  I suggest you report the bug to the typescript-mode maintainer.

Comment: This still hasn't fixed after 3 months. The workaround is not to press `TAB` to format the code after putting a newline after dot.